# Why does Identity not show all of my claims?

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims

I am using the ASP.NET Identity library. I added a claim, and I do not get it back when I ask for all of a user's claims. I even restarted my application in case it doesn't update right away. Still no luck.

Code to get the claims:

```
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; } = default!;

private async Task InitializeSchedulerData()
{
        var authenticationState = await AuthenticationStateTask;
        var claims = authenticationState.User.Claims.ToList();
```

This gets me (from the debugger):

```
Count = 5
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: 091a0828-6cc5-4cee-bf3a-a2348872de94}
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: colorado@thielen.com}
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress: colorado@thielen.com}
{AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp: JKNDXBICJOPUYON4DIEZK2OD4RODU5NZ}
{Admin: State:Colorado}
```

While in the database, the table AspNetUserClaims is:

```
Id  UserId  ClaimType   ClaimValue
1   091a0828-6cc5-4cee-bf3a-a2348872de94    Admin   State:Colorado
2   c3a84b03-c3f3-423d-82cf-2c885aca2233    Admin   Campaign:Hick4Colorado
3   12e37c4f-149e-466b-875a-1965a575f5c9    Admin   Campaign:Frisch4Colorado
4   487e9d8a-58d4-49f8-8100-3e014f914012    Director    Campaign:Frisch4Colorado
5   a00342e5-b7b7-4426-8868-a1c0ff82f96d    Admin   *
10  034225c9-e6ff-408e-be77-f5e292078a0a    Executive   State:Alabama
11  77325df9-6147-46e2-a1c3-0bf0e32ba710    Executive   County:Alabama_Baldwin
12  091a0828-6cc5-4cee-bf3a-a2348872de94    Executive   Campaign:Hick4Colorado
```

Any idea why it isn't finding the new entry? The UserId entry for both matches.

**Update:** I exited and restarted Visual Studio. Now it does show up. But why is that required? I need it to show up immediately. How do I accomplish that?

**Update 2:** It looks like it needs to have `SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);` called to update the user/claims held in a cookie (which explains why exiting VS also resolved it). The problem is, you can't call SignInManager in blazor code.

Is there any downside to, when I need to do this, call an ASP.NET MVC page (placed with the other Identity MVC pages) that in OnGet() calls `SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);` and then redirects to a url I pass in the call to this page?

I know we're supposed to use OnPost(). But there's no way to redirect to a page and have it call OnPost. So placing this in OnGet() seems the only option.

What problems do I cause or security holes do I create if I do this in an OnGet()?